# GIT: get out from git diff mode

Tags: windows, git

I want to see changes to a specific file using git, so I use the command

```
git diff file_name
```

everything is fine, but I don't know how to get out from this mode.

`ESC` does not work

`RETURN`  does not work

`CTRL + Z`  does not work

`CTRL + C`  does not work

`CTRL + X`  does not work

[image]

Comment: Try `q`, looks like you're looking at `less`, the pagination tool used.

Comment: Press "q". If it doesn't work, try "esc", ":", and "q". If this doesn't work either, try ctrl-c or ctrl-z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type in `q` or `:q` and `Enter` to quit from read mode.